Does iterating this function with primes as fixed points always result in a prime?
Define $f(n) $ as the largest divisor of $n$ smaller than $n$. (undefined at $n=1$)
Define a sequence as
$$a_1 = k$$
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + f(a_{n-1}) - 1$$
where $k \geq 2$.
Note that $a_n = a_{n+1}$ if and only if $a_n$ is a prime.
Does this sequence eventually result in a prime for all $k$?
I've verified that it's true for all $k < 6156$ with a script.
It's been verified true for $k \leq 10^6$ by Greg Martin in the comments.
As a side question, if we define $g(k)$ as the prime this sequence leads to (if it does lead to a prime) starting with $k$, are there any bounds or asymptotic formulas for $g(k)/k$?
Edit:
A small curiosity: define $n$ to be a spiking value if for all $k < n$,
$g(k) < g(n)$.
$16$ out of the first $19$ spiking values are squarefree.
Edit 2: Updates and small refinements.

If $s(n)$ denotes the smallest prime factor of $n$ , we can rewrite this is $$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{s(a_{n-1})}-1$$

There's definitely not going to be an asymptotic formula for $g(k)/k$, or even for $a_2/a_1$, since the latter ratio is $1$ for primes but around $\frac43$ for multiples of $3$.

Some data: for $k\le10^6$, the largest value of $g(k)$ is $g(470002)=196808591311151$, which took 122 iterations. This was also the largest value of $\log g(k)/\log k$ in that range—the log ratio was about 2.52. 50% of those ratios were below 1.076, while 90% were below 1.23, and 99% below 1.464.

More data: For $k \in [2,10^8]$: all sequences terminate at primes; $k=98,112,697$ gives the greatest number of iterations, $305$; $\max g = {}$ $g(55,245,322) = {}$ $g(61,241,178) = {}$ $g(82,867,982) = {}$ $g(90,768,174) = {}$ $g(91,861,766) = {}$ $4,396,502,880,258,324,850,443,328,819$; and $\min g(k)/k = 1$, the median is $3.375$, the mean is $3.60{\dots}\times10^{12}$, and the maximum is $7.95{\dots} \times 10^{19}$ -- this pretty much indicates $g(k)$ is usually only a few times $k$ except for (very) rare huge spikes.

For $k \in [2,10^8]$, there are 39 spiking values: $2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 18, 30, 34, 66, 130, 322, 514, 1090, 1282, 1618, 2154, 2770, 2898, 4434, 6156, 11,010, 16,450, 21,366, 44,602, 121,506, 182,770, 205,314, 229,570, 275,590, 302,290, 356,698, 470,002, 1,079,242, 1,088,002, 1,742,274, 2,814,474, 6,730,914, 39,293,514, 55,245,322$.  Looking at a log-log plot, these seem to grow faster than polynomially in $k$.
